# apache2 - php5 file upload and post max size

Tags: apache2, php

I've installed from the official repos the LAMP server.
In the file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, I've changed:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

to

```
post_max_size = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
```

After that, I've restarted the apache2 server and also the notebook but when I launch the `phpinfo` I got `post_max_size` set to `8MB`. The only way to resolve this bug is to set the `php_value .....` into an `.htaccess` but this is not what I want.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 16):

1. Create a php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and open it with your browser.
2. Look for **Loaded Configuration File** (this shows the actual conf. file in use) and edit `upload_max_filesize` and set `post_max_size` to the same value (or make it 0 to disable limit) in that file in root mode.
3. Execute: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I changed these values in these files and now it's working:

```
➜find /etc -name 'php.ini'
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/embed/php.ini
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

You must set php settings for php "scripts", not only for Apache.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions worked but this superb solution did.

1. create a php file with `<? phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Look for "Scan this dir for additional .ini files".
3. Go to the above directory and create user.ini file like:-

   ```
    post_max_size = 1500M
    upload_max_filesize = 1500M
   ```
4. Restart Apache sudo service apache2 restart
5. Reload the `phpinfo();` file. You will thanks me :)

Comment: This is the _only_ thing that's worked for me. Hosting on Digital Ocean, using Wordpress with PHP5, Apache2, and Ubuntu 14.04. My god, thank you.

Comment: Yes buddy I thank you for that, very clever solution! none of the previous one did works for me